# Converting string type data to integer in Jasper Pro Ad Hoc Editor?

Tags: string, integer, type-conversion, jasperserver, adhoc

I am using Jasper Pro to create a report using Ad Hoc Editor.
In the database i am currently using, i have a data called qualifications and year_of_qualifications. I am trying to use the year_of_qualifications to get the highest qualifications, but the database has set year_of_qualifications into string, not integer or any numerical data type.

Is there a way to convert data type from string to numerical values in jasper ad hoc?

Seems that i couldn't find the solutions anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have built "Functions". You can use them to cast from string. I've marked them on this screen: [image: built_functions]